# Passing different column values to where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, in-subquery

```
    SELECT pims.icicimedicalexaminerreport.id, 
       pims.icicimerfemaleapplicant.adversemenstrualid, 
       pims.icicimerfemaleapplicant.pregnantid, 
       pims.icicimerfemaleapplicant.miscarriageabortionid, 
       pims.icicimerfemaleapplicant.breastdiseaseid, 
       pims.pimscase.tiannumber 
FROM   pims.pimscase 
       INNER JOIN pims.digitization 
               ON pims.pimscase.digitizationid = pims.digitization.id 
       INNER JOIN pims.medicalexaminerreport 
               ON pims.digitization.medicalexaminerreportid = 
                  pims.medicalexaminerreport.id 
       INNER JOIN pims.icicimedicalexaminerreport 
               ON pims.medicalexaminerreport.id = 
                  pims.icicimedicalexaminerreport.id 
       INNER JOIN pims.icicimerfemaleapplicant 
               ON pims.icicimedicalexaminerreport.id = 
                  pims.icicimerfemaleapplicant.id 
WHERE  pims.pimscase.tiannumber = 'ICICI1234567890'
```

which gives me the following output

[image: Query Output]

Now I want to use the above output values to select the rows from the table "YesNoAnswerWithObservation"

I imagine it should look something like this `Select * from YesNoAnswerWithObservation Where Id in (22,27,26,...23)`

Only instead of typing the values inside **IN** clause I want to use the values in each column resulting from above-mentioned query.

I tried the below code but it returns all the rows in the table  rather than rows mentioned inside the In

```
SELECT pims.yesnoanswerwithobservation.observation, 
       graphitegtccore.yesnoquestion.description, 
       pims.yesnoanswerwithobservation.id ObservationId 
FROM   pims.yesnoanswerwithobservation 
       INNER JOIN graphitegtccore.yesnoquestion 
               ON pims.yesnoanswerwithobservation.yesnoanswerid = 
                  graphitegtccore.yesnoquestion.id 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT pims.icicimedicalexaminerreport.id, 
                      pims.icicimerfemaleapplicant.adversemenstrualid, 
                      pims.icicimerfemaleapplicant.pregnantid, 
                      pims.icicimerfemaleapplicant.pelvicorgandiseaseid, 
                      pims.icicimerfemaleapplicant.miscarriageabortionid, 
                      pims.icicimerfemaleapplicant.gynocologicalscanid, 
                      pims.icicimerfemaleapplicant.breastdiseaseid, 
                      pims.pimscase.tiannumber 
               FROM   pims.pimscase 
                      INNER JOIN pims.digitization 
                              ON pims.pimscase.digitizationid = 
                                 pims.digitization.id 
                      INNER JOIN pims.medicalexaminerreport 
                              ON pims.digitization.medicalexaminerreportid = 
                                 pims.medicalexaminerreport.id 
                      INNER JOIN pims.icicimedicalexaminerreport 
                              ON pims.medicalexaminerreport.id = 
                                 pims.icicimedicalexaminerreport.id 
                      INNER JOIN pims.icicimerfemaleapplicant 
                              ON pims.icicimedicalexaminerreport.id = 
                                 pims.icicimerfemaleapplicant.id 
               WHERE  pims.pimscase.tiannumber = 'ICICI1234567890')
```

[image]

Any help or a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Will UNPIVOT and Temp table be useful here?

Comment: "Only instead of typing the values inside where clause I want to use the above-mentioned query."  Your query returns many different columns.  It is unclear what you intend.

Comment: I agree with @nevas, UNPIVOT would solve the problem.

Comment: Unpivot worked. Thanks, but will the query performance degrade when the number of columns to Unpivot increases I'm thinking around 25 columns

Comment: You coul use `CROSS APPLY`, but since you are pivoting a single row, I don't think there will be any significant performance improvement. See here for more info: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/an-alternative-better-method-to-unpivot-sql-spackle

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want the *id*s from the first query:

```
SELECT awo.observation, ynq.description, ynq.id as ObservationId 
FROM pims.yesnoanswerwithobservation awo JOIN
     graphitegtccore.yesnoquestion ynq
      ON awo.yesnoanswerid = ynq.id 
WHERE ynq.id = (SELECT mer.id 
                FROM pims.pimscase c JOIN
                     pims.digitization d
                     ON c.digitizationid = d.id JOIN
                     pims.medicalexaminerreport mer
                     ON d.medicalexaminerreportid = mer.id JOIN
                     pims.icicimedicalexaminerreport imer
                     ON mer.id = imer.id JOIN
                     pims.icicimerfemaleapplicant ifa
                     ON imer.id = ifa.id 
                WHERE c.tiannumber = 'ICICI1234567890'
              ) ;
```

Notice that table aliases make the query much easier to write and to read.